# Passing a global variable into a function in python?

Tags: python, global-variables

In a situation like the following... Which would be the "correct" way to access the global variable within a function? I am new to python, but I assumed it would be the fun1() case, (unless you were reassigning the variable) but I have seen it done like fun2() and I am confused why you would want to do that.

```
GVAR = 100


def fun1(a, b):
    return a + b + GVAR


def fun2(a, b, gvar):
    return a + b + gvar


def fun3(a, b, GVAR):
    return a + b + GVAR


fun1(a, b)
fun2(a, b, GVAR)
fun3(a, b, GVAR)
```

thank you.

Comment: That depends on why `GVAR` is a global variable in the first place. All three are correct: `fun1` uses the global variable, and `fun2` and `fun3` (identical aside from the parameter name chosen) takes an argument that may or may not come from a global variable.

Comment: `fun1` is better as long as you actually want to use `GVAR` in all cases.  If you wanted to be able to swap it out in certain cases (maybe for testing?) `fun2` would be appropriate.  A combination approach would be to make it a default -- `def fun(a, b, gvar=GVAR)`.  `fun3` is bad style because it violates naming conventions (and confusingly shadows the global).

Comment: Note, you don't pass *variables into functions*, you pass *objects*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very proficient in python but I believe the first way is the correct way as a global variable is accessible at the global and local scope if I recall correctly. For example, this should operate properly.

```
x = 300

def myfunc():
  print(x)
```